# SQL - How to count # of instances greater than 1 second apart?

Tags: sql, time, dateadd

I want to count "instances" on an account that are more than one second apart.

I have something like this below

| Account # | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 10:02:01 |
| 123456 | 10:02:02 |
| 123456 | 10:10:02 |

From the table above, I want the answer to be 2. There are 2 groups for the same account that are more than 1 second apart.

I tried to use some variations of the dateadd function

Select count(*)
From a
Where Time NOT BETWEEN dateadd(second, -1, time) AND dateadd(second, 1, time)

but can't quite get where I need to get it..
I guess I could do something like count the number between and subtract by not between or something...

Any ideas?

Comment: why would it be 2 and not one? do you want it to be equal or greater than 1 second?

Comment: So if there were records with the times of "10:02:01", "10:02:02" and "10:02:03" would this be one "group" or since the "10:02:01" and "10:02:03" are more than one second apart would that be two groups? If that makes one group, then it seems like an "islands and gaps" sort of problem.

Comment: Yes, If the time stamps were as you mentioned I would still want the answer to be 2. I want them grouped by less than or equal to 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   Account
        ,count(case when sec_diff > 1 then 1 end) as cnt
from      
  
(
select   *
        ,datediff(second, lag(time) over(partition by account order by time), time) as sec_diff
from     t
) t
  
group by Account
```

| Account | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hx4fGbXX)

Comment: I want the answer to be 2 though

Comment: you need to fix your question then since there's one second between 10:02:01 10:02:02 and more than one second between 10:02:02  and 10:10:02